# How to use 'DBCPConnectionPoolLookup' in 'ExecuteGroovyScript' processor?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I want to use 'DBCPConnectionPoolLookup' controller service in 'ExecuteGroovyScript' processor. I set '*database.name*' But I get this Error:

[image]

This is 'ExecuteGroovyScript' configs:

[image]
I found someone who had [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57883900/how-to-use-dbcpconnectionpoollookup-controllor-service-in-executegroovyscript) and solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888447/exception-cannot-get-a-connection-pool-error-timeout-waiting-for-idle-object), but his approach to solve the problem is not complete.

I think I should use CTL as described in answer part of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57888447/exception-cannot-get-a-connection-pool-error-timeout-waiting-for-idle-object) but I got this Error:

[image]

This is my config:

[image]

Please let me know what is the problem?

**update**:
I removed try/catch from code and got these errors:

Using `SQL.db`:

[image]

Using `CTL.sql`:

[image]

Full log:

```
2019-10-17 22:27:12,685 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=bb9d644c-016d-1000-5485-c915da52bbfb] org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:474)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1514.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService$getConnection.call(Unknown Source)
    at Scriptffffffffa8c699bc.run(Scriptffffffffa8c699bc.groovy:8)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:449)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:470)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:451)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:365)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
2019-10-17 22:27:13,194 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=bb9d644c-016d-1000-5485-c915da52bbfb] org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:474)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService.getConnection(DBCPService.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1514.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy100.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPService$getConnection.call(Unknown Source)
    at Scriptffffffffa8c699bc.run(Scriptffffffffa8c699bc.groovy:8)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:449)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:142)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1563)
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPool.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPool.java:470)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Timeout waiting for idle object
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:451)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:365)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
    ... 23 common frames omitted
2019-10-17 22:31:58,045 WARN [Timer-Driven Process Thread-4] o.a.n.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask Administratively Yielding ExecuteGroovyScript[id=bb9d644c-016d-1000-5485-c915da52bbfb] due to uncaught Exception: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128 cannot be cast to org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.sql.OSql
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128 cannot be cast to org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.sql.OSql
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onFinitSQL(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:371)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:464)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2019-10-17 22:31:59,045 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-2] o.a.n.p.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript ExecuteGroovyScript[id=bb9d644c-016d-1000-5485-c915da52bbfb] org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Attributes must contain an attribute name 'database.name': org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Attributes must contain an attribute name 'database.name'
org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: Attributes must contain an attribute name 'database.name'
    at org.apache.nifi.dbcp.DBCPConnectionPoolLookup.getConnection(DBCPConnectionPoolLookup.java:124)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1514.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:87)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.getConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onInitSQL(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:339)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.groovyx.ExecuteGroovyScript.onTrigger(ExecuteGroovyScript.java:439)
    at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1162)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:209)
    at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Script Code for `SQL.db`:

```
flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
def RawData =flowFile.read().getText("UTF-8")
def JobId = flowFile.ExtractJobId
def params = [RawData,JobId]
def result = SQL.db.executeInsert("INSERT INTO ExtractFiles (RawData,JobId,CreateTimestamp,UpdateTimestamp) VALUES (?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)",params)
flowFile.'ExtractFileId' = result[0][0]
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```

Script code for `CTL.sql`:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
def RawData =flowFile.read().getText("UTF-8")
def JobId = flowFile.ExtractJobId
def params = [RawData,JobId]
def myDbConnection = CTL.sql.getConnection(flowFile.getAttributes())
def myClientDb = new Sql(myDbConnection)
def result = myClientDb.executeInsert("INSERT INTO ExtractFiles (RawData,JobId,CreateTimestamp,UpdateTimestamp) VALUES (?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)",params)
flowFile.'ExtractFileId' = result[0][0]
REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
```

Comment: use SQL.mydb instead of CTL. So, you don't need to get connection. Just use `SQL.mydb.executeInsert`. Also try-catch is not necessary - failurelure strategy already does the same.

Comment: @daggett I want to use 'DBCPConnectionPoolLookup', and it doesn't work with SQL.*

Comment: ok. remove try-catch and show full stacktrace from log.

Comment: @daggett I removed try/catch and added errors in update section.

Comment: What's now in line 8 of the script?

Comment: @daggett I added the code to the question.

Comment: @daggett I think I found the problem, but I don't know how to solve it. I restarted Nifi and used script for CTL.sql as Added above. It works well and add info to Database but after process 8 flowfiles, shows this error: `ExecuteGroovyScript[id=d54c3e2f-a38e-19a0-cba3-2125d58f1f4b] org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object: org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Timeout waiting for idle object`

Comment: @daggett I think, the connection should be closed, but I don't know how to close open connections.

Comment: connectionObj.close()

Comment: @daggett I added `myClientDb.close()` after `REL_SUCCESS << flowFile` and it works. Is it true or should I add it in try/cache/finaly?

Comment: @daggett thank you so much for your help, we found the solution at same time :)

Comment: better to close in finally. catch you don't need. or in catch re-throw the same exception to avoid loosing real exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used CTL object and edited the code to solve the problem:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
def dbConnection = CTL.db.getConnection(flowFile.getAttributes())
def clientDb = new Sql(dbConnection)
try {
    def RawData =flowFile.read().getText("UTF-8")
    def JobId = flowFile.ExtractJobId
    def params = [RawData,JobId]
    def result = clientDb.executeInsert("INSERT INTO ExtractFiles (RawData,JobId,CreateTimestamp,UpdateTimestamp) VALUES (?,?,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)",params)
    flowFile.'ExtractFileId' = result[0][0]
    REL_SUCCESS << flowFile
} catch (Exception e) {
    throw e;
} finally {
    clientDb.close();
}
```

I added clientDb.close() as [@daggett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1276664/daggett) said in comments.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to close connection after SQL  SELECT in NIFI Groove script.

```
import org.apache.nifi.controller.ControllerService
import groovy.sql.Sql
def lookup = context.controllerServiceLookup
def dbServiceName = "PgSQLConnenctor"
def dbcpServiceId = lookup.getControllerServiceIdentifiers(ControllerService).find {
    cs -> lookup.getControllerServiceName(cs) == dbServiceName
}
def conn = lookup.getControllerService(dbcpServiceId)?.getConnection()
   

flowFile = session.get()
if(!flowFile) return
try {
    csuid_message_ID = flowFile.getAttribute('message_id')
    csuid_spp = flowFile.getAttribute('spp')
    def sql = new Sql(conn)
    //TO THOMETHING
    sql.close() //<-- this solution for me !!!! We need to close connection.
}
```