# Why CTL doesn't work in ExecuteGroovyScript processor with Apache NiFi 1.10.0?

Tags: groovy, apache-nifi

I've used CTL in ExecuteGroovyScript processor to connect to database which is selected by *database.name* due to this problem [DBCPConnectionPoolLookup problem in ExecuteGroovyScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58430317/how-to-use-dbcpconnectionpoollookup-in-executegroovyscript-processor). after upgrading NiFi to new version (1.10.0), the processors show this error:
[image: processor error]

and this is my processor configuration:

[image: processor configuration]

Please let me know the problem.

Comment: seems to be a bug. easy reproduced. let's wait for nifi developers... the source where error generated: https://github.com/apache/nifi/blob/master/nifi-nar-bundles/nifi-framework-bundle/nifi-framework/nifi-framework-core-api/src/main/java/org/apache/nifi/controller/AbstractComponentNode.java#L746

Comment: Thanks for your attention, I opened an issue in [Jira](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6852).

Answer (score 0):

I started testing version 1.10.0 myself recently and that was one of the things I ran in to as well. Try using SQL.* (ex: SQL.db) for your property name as that is used specifically for DBCP services. If you need to access other services that still can be done by looking up the service by name in your Groovy script as a workaround but based on Jira activity, I see this bug is already being worked on and hopefully will be fixed in next release. I hope this helps.